# Как правильно сверстать этот блок, не используя таблицу?

Tags: html, css

Вот сам блок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так сделал я и меня интересует, на сколько такое решение правильное? Или все же лучше делать через таблицу? И там еще hover, по всей видимости окрашивает границы вокруг ссылки, это делается через JS, если да, то можете подсказать уже готовые решения?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без таблицы, с эффектом.

```js
let table = document.querySelector('.table'),
    bgs = 100; // background-size / 2

window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let rect = table.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = (e.clientX - rect.left) - bgs,
      y = (e.clientY - rect.top) - bgs;
  
  table.style.setProperty('--effect-x', x+'px');
  table.style.setProperty('--effect-y', y+'px');
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: var(--effect-x, -100px) var(--effect-y, -100px);
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  padding: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.table__row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.table__col {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.table__col:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="table__col"></div>
    <div class="table__col"></div>
    <div class="table__col"></div>
    <div class="table__col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="table__col"></div>
    <div class="table__col"></div>
    <div class="table__col"></div>
    <div class="table__col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

тебе поможет 2 решения грид или флекс , проще сделать через флекс затем закрасить боржер в нужние цвета вот тебе шпаргалка (https://tpverstak.ru/flex-cheatsheet/) с гридом меньше кода получиться (https://tpverstak.ru/grid/) в конце просто добавь бордеру цвет градиет и просто белый где ныжно